# NSString stringWithFormat adding a newline by itself

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, nslog

Why does this:

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/profile/%@/?s_iphone=true", author];
NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
```

Output this:

```
http://www.example.com/profile/AuthorName
            /?s_iphone=true
```

Needless to say the url won't load b/c there is a newline added to the string by itself. I've tried removing whitesapces/newlines and still had the same output. Its driving me crazy.

Matt

Comment: Have you examined `author` to see if the newline exists just before the code above is called?

Comment: Thanks, forgot to think about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this -

```
NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/profile/%@/?s_iphone=true", [author stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
```

It will fix any new line characters at the beginning and end of your `author` string.

Comment: Thanks, I have a custom method just for this purpose and some extra, i ran it through and fixed my issue. Sometimes just not thinking clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Author definitely has a new line in it. Try this:

`NSLog(@"The author is %@ on a new line?", author);`

Comment: Yep, weird that my method to remove newlines didn't work on the whole string, but would work on just the variable. Author was a string taken from XML which does have nasty newlines at the end. Thanks.